How to use Python to view online users on Telegram?
I'd like to check with the current online user and when the last time of access is if it's offline.
Below is my code, but there are two problems.
First of all, I'm the only one who's online. All other users are marked "recently" and not checked even though they're talking in real time.
Second, users who are marked "Recently" are not viewed for recent access times.
Of course, I have administrative rights.
Is there a good way to solve these two problems?
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest

from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty, UserStatusOnline, UserStatusRecently, UserStatusOffline
from datetime import datetime

api_id = 12345
api_hash = '12345'
phone = '12345'
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))

chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups = []

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
    offset_date=last_date,
    offset_id=0,
    offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
    limit=chunk_size,
    hash=0
))
chats.extend(result.chats)


for chat in chats:
    groups.append(chat)

print('Choose a group to scrape members from:')

for i, g in enumerate(groups):
    print(f"{i} - {g.title}")

target_group=groups[4]

print('Fetching Members...')
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)
print(all_participants)
online_users = [user for user in all_participants if isinstance(user.status, UserStatusOnline) or isinstance(user.status, UserStatusRecently) or isinstance(user.status, UserStatusOffline)]
print(f"Total online/recently active participants: {len(online_users)}")
for user in online_users:
    name = f"{user.first_name or ''} {user.last_name or ''}".strip()
    status_time = None

    if isinstance(user.status, UserStatusOnline):
        status_time = user.status.expires
        status = "Online"
    elif isinstance(user.status, UserStatusRecently):
        status_time = ""
        status = "Recently"
    elif isinstance(user.status, UserStatusOffline):
        status_time = user.status.was_online
        status = "Offline"

    if status_time:
        status_time_str = status_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    else:
        status_time_str = "Unknown"

    print(
        f'User ID: {user.id}, Username: {user.username}, Name: {name}, Status: {status}, Last Seen: {status_time_str}')

I'd like to know who the online users are and if you've recently accessed them, when did you access them.

The Telegram server does not always send "online" information. Most official clients combine both the real, server-side last seen with when they last sent a message. You would need to do the same (check if they have sent a message recently and assume they are online).
